# Question about tkinter's loop and possible solutions

Tags: python, tkinter

Basically im trying to create a tkinter UI together with a audio listening infinite loop. My problem is the after() method does not really work as your traditional infinite loop with an exit condition.

I would want to keep both tkinter's main loop and my own, so my infinite loop would be constantly listening until the exit condition is met then i break out the loop.

I was looking at multithreading but im not too sure how to do this with tkinter since im new to tkinter in general

Ultimately id want to do this

```
def listen(event):
   while 1:
       #listennnn
       #exit condition then break


root = Tk()
deploy = Button(root, text="Listen")
deploy.bind("<Button-1>", listen)

deploy.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Does this work for you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459083/how-do-you-run-your-own-code-alongside-tkinters-event-loop

Comment: You are binding an endless function to the button. When you press it, the `listen` would run. Can you explain more what you want exactly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you run your own code alongside Tkinter's event loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459083/how-do-you-run-your-own-code-alongside-tkinters-event-loop)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an exit condition with this construct:

```
def listen(event='dummy_event'):
    if exit_condition:
        return
    do_the_listening_thinghy()
    root.after(100, listen)


exit_condition = False

root = Tk()
deploy_btn = Button(root, text="Listen", command=listen)    
deploy_btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options.

### Create your own event loop

Instead of calling `root.mainloop()`, write your own loop that does whatever audio capture you need and then calls `root.update()` to process Tkinter events.

This might need some careful tuning. You don't want to loose any audio, nor do you want the GUI to become unresponsive.

An similar alternative to this:

### Integrate `asyncio` in your `tkinter` program

If you are familiar with the asyncio style, this might do very well. It also has support in the language.

Unfortunately `asyncio` is still kind of a work in progress. So the examples you'll find might be out of date and even unusable.

### Use a separate process for audio

Launch a `multiprocessing.Process` to do the audio capture. Use a `multiprocessing.Pipe` to send commands to the process and to receive audio data (using `after`).
You should probably create this process *before* creating the root window.

The biggest plusses of this method are:

- it cannot interfere with the GUI process,
- it can be tested separately from the GUI,
- any audio processing can be done in the second process (or even a *third process*) without interfering with the GUI.

### Using a separate thread for audio

Since audio involves I/O, this might be a good fit for threading.

It won't do if you also need to do CPU-intensive processing of the audio data. In CPython, only one thread at a time can be executing Python bytecode. So when the second thread crunching numbers, your GUI thread might be starved of run time.